# Karate DSL - How to use afterFeature with @Karate.Test

Tags: karate

I used `configure afterFeature` with `@Karate.Test`, but it seems that `afterFeature function` is never called. However, when I run test with `@jupiter.api.Test void testParallel() {}`, it works fine.

Question: Is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance for your helps,

users.feature

```
Feature: Sample test

  Background:
    * configure afterScenario = function() { karate.log("I'm afterScenario"); }
    * configure afterFeature = function() { karate.log("I'm afterFeature"); }

  Scenario: Scenario 1
    * print "I'm Scenario 1"

  Scenario: Scenario 2
    * print "I'm Scenario 2"
```

UsersRunner.java - Does NOT work

```java
class UsersRunner {
    
    @Karate.Test
    Karate testUsers() {
        return Karate.run("users").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}

/* karate.log
11:44:01.598 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
11:44:02.404 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:44:02.434 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] I'm Scenario 1 
11:44:02.435 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - I'm afterScenario 
11:44:02.447 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:44:02.450 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] I'm Scenario 2 
11:44:02.450 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - I'm afterScenario 
*/
```

ExamplesTest.java - Works

```java
class ExamplesTest {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:examples")
                .tags("~@ignore")
                //.outputCucumberJson(true)
                .parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}

/* karate.log
11:29:48.904 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
11:29:48.908 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Suite - backed up existing 'target/karate-reports' dir to: target/karate-reports_1621308588907
11:29:49.676 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:29:49.676 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:29:49.707 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] I'm Scenario 2 
11:29:49.707 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] I'm Scenario 1 
11:29:49.707 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.intuit.karate - I'm afterScenario 
11:29:49.707 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - I'm afterScenario 
11:29:49.709 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - I'm afterFeature 
11:29:50.116 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Suite - <<pass>> feature 1 of 1 (0 remaining) classpath:examples/users/users.feature
*/
```

Comment: This was marked `Won't fix` as explained in https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1588. However, the README has been updated to avoid similar confusion in the future https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/v1.1.0#environment-specific-config

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to the latest 1.0.1 - if you still see the problem, it is a bug and please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue